# What are hydrodynamic and non-hydrodynamic modes in the Navier-Stokes equations and how do they relate to stability?

Tags: stability-in-odes, stability-theory, linearization

I'm new here. I have been reading articles on Navier-Stokes equation and the stability analysis by studying different modes. However I am still confused by what is meant by modes as in the context of Navier-Stokes equations, how are they computed, how are they differentiated (hydrodynamic and non-hydrodynamic modes), and how these are linked to linearization + stability analysis. Most books seem to dive straight into the formulas without enough background info. I am also familiar with the Fourier analysis/Fourier transform; it is just that it hasn't clicked in my head how all these things are related together and where to start from.

What I am looking for is: not exactly looking for detailed mathematical derivations, **just a relatively easy explanation on how all these concepts relate together**, and then I can go on from there and continue the research myself.

Thank you all in advance for any help/advice/links! Let me know if I am missing info or if I should rephrase my question, still learning :D

Comment: The review "Unified Extended Irreversible Thermodynamics and the stability of relativistic theories for dissipation" (https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2105.15184) explains linear stability, hydro and non-hydro modes for different systems including relativistic and non-relativistic Navier-Stokes (see e.g. sec 3.3).